# Excel FREQUENCY WITH IF AND

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Thanks to Stack Overflow I have solved one problem, but now I am trying to expand the formula.

I have four columns, and I want to try the following.

If column F equals `urgent` and column G equals `p1`, then count the number of rows but count duplicate rows as 1

I have tried the following

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(AND(F1:F8="urgent",G1:G8="p1"),MATCH(H1:H8&I1:I8,H1:H8&I1:I8,0)),ROW(Sheet1!H1:H8)-1)>0))
```

[image]

The formula will work by not using the AND and only checking one column basically `IF(F1:F8="urgent",MATCH.....`

Therefore I am unable to run the AND logic as the result is `#VALUE`

I can run `IF(AND(G1="p1",F1="urgent"),TRUE)` this will correctly state if the condition is true or false

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by not using `AND`

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(F1:F8="urgent",IF(G1:G8="p1",MATCH(H1:H8&I1:I8,H1:H8&I1:I8,0))),ROW(Sheet1!H1:H8)-1)>0))`

Just using `IF(F1:F8="urgent",IF(G1:G8="p1", MATCH ....`